# How to access DefaultTableModel from another class

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I intend to have a form (FLlistes) that shows a table populated with data from taken from a database with hibernate. The problem is that I don't know how to access the table (or table model) from the class I use to create the queries.

I created a jtable in a JInternal frame like this:

```
public class FLlistes extends JInternalFrame {

    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    //some code

    String[] columns = {"Id","Date", "Place", "Total"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
    table = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(49, 176, 732, 361);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(model);

    //some code
}
```

I have another class that makes the queries to populate the table with Hibernate:

```
public class AccionsBD {

    public static void GetALLLlistes() {
        String jql = "select llc from LlistaCompra llc";

        EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<LlistaCompra> q = entityManager.createQuery(jql,LlistaCompra.class);
        List<LlistaCompra> llistes = q.getResultList();

        for (LlistaCompra llista: llistes) {                
            String[] row = {Integer.toString(llista.getIdLlista()), llista.getData().toString(), llista.getLloc()};
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that i don't know how to access model in `model.addRow(row);` in order to fill the table

Comment: Can you pass the _model_ as a parameter to method `GetALLLlistes`, i.e. `public static void GetALLLlistes(DefaultTableModel model)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `FLlistes`  as singletone and provide a getter method for `DefaultTableModel` property. Then you can access `getModel()` from singletone object .

```
public class FLlistes extends JInternalFrame {

private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel model;

public DefaultTableModel  getModel(){
  return model;
}

//Singletone implemenation 
}
```