# JTable not showing any data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a class that is meant to show a JTable populated with data taken from a database with hibernate:

```
 public class FLlistes extends JInternalFrame {

    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    //some code for more components of the form

    String[] columns = {"Id","Data", "Lloc"};
        model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0) {    
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columna) {
                if (columna == 2)
                    return LocalDate.class;
                return Object.class;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

    table = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(49, 176, 732, 361);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    //some code for more components of the form
}
```

Then I have a class that makes the queries with hibernate. The next method is supposed to collect data from a table and populate the table I created before.

```
public class AccionsBD {

public static void GetAllLlistes() {
    String jql = "select llc from LlistaCompra llc";

    EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<LlistaCompra> q = entityManager.createQuery(jql,LlistaCompra.class);
    List<LlistaCompra> llistes = q.getResultList();

    FLlistes fl = new FLlistes();

    for (LlistaCompra llista: llistes) {    
        System.out.println(llista.getIdLlista());
        System.out.println(llista.getData());
        System.out.println(llista.getLloc());

        Object[] objFila = new Object[3];
        objFila[0] = llista.getIdLlista();
        objFila[1] = llista.getData();
        objFila[2] = llista.getLloc();
        fl.getModel().addRow(objFila);
    }
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

The purpose of the System.out.println inside the loop is only to check that the query works. The query is working fine, I tried debugging and the end of the loop objFila contains all the correct data, but the table in the form never shows anything besides the table header. What am I missing?

Also, for some reason sometimes when I run the app the form shows up, and somtimes it doesn't. It does this without even changing the code. Why does this happen?

Edit: this is my getter:

```
public DefaultTableModel getModel() {
        return model;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `getModel()` method of  your `FLlistes ` class?

Comment: @PeterLustig have a look at the OPs [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564128/how-to-access-defaulttablemodel-from-another-class#comment107147300_60564128) that preceded this one.

Comment: @PeterLustig I have just edited this question and added the getModel()

Comment: @winter Where are you initializing the `model` variable? I can only see `modelLlistes = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0) ` but no statement like `model = new DefaultTableModel()`

Comment: It's working fine for me.  I'm guessing your getModel() isn't returning the correct model or you're setting the model in the class and setting a different model in the table.  As an aside: You should be extending AbstractTableModel instead of using DefaultTableModel.  The default is OK for quick and dirty output, but you'll get into bad habits using it consistently.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph in your question. `JTable` listens for changes to its model and updates its display accordingly. I'm guessing that you update the model on a thread that is not the _Event Dispatch Thread_ (EDT), hence the problem. All _Swing_ code that changes the GUI components must run on the EDT. I think you should reconsider the answer you accepted to your previous question. Alternatively, consider populating the table model before assigning it to the `JTable`.

Comment: @PeterLustig sorry, the important variables are tranlsated and I forgot to change this one. model is initialized right before the first Override tag, if that makes sense

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) `scrollPane.setBounds(49, 176, 732, 361);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).